# How to read values from nested asp.net DataGrid using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, grid

I need to read the value from a nested data grid in aspx page using Javascript.

Here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <asp:DataGrid ID="sampleData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="sampleData_ItemDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="City" DataField="City" />
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="State" DataField="State" />
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Inner Data">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DataGrid ID="innerData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
                                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="City" DataField="City" />
                                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="State" DataField="State" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:DataGrid>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Show us the javascript-function. What if paging is/will be enabled? You can only read the values that are currently visible.

Comment: @Tim.. I dont have the java script right now. but i need java script thats why i posted question here. Yes its enough to read the values which are currently visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the `id` which is generated for the component on browsers `view source page`
Probably it would be iterating by incremental numbers. I am not aware of `<asp:Datagrid>`

Get the component in javsacript by using `document.getElementById('innerData')` and the values accordingly.

if its a table then by `document.getElementById('innerData').getElementsByTagName('td');`

Comment: Yep, niksvp approach should do the trick, and then you can extract the data from the cells using their innerHTML attribute, for instance for the first cell value you can use: document.getElementById("sampleData").getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML